# Как програмно прокрутить ScroolBar в ListBox в конец списка

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Как програмно прокрутить `ScroolBar` в  `ListBox` в конец списка

Comment: Добавь свой код

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что самый простой способ - установить свойство TopIndex соответствующим образом.

Пример:

```
int visibleItems = listBox.ClientSize.Height / listBox.ItemHeight;
listBox.TopIndex = Math.Max(listBox.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796820/5598926)